# Change data type within a recordset by VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl

I'm trying to change the data type with an [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) recordset. I got the record from an Excel file using SSIS and save it into an object variable, 'User::CriteriaResult'.

When I try to use a `foreach` loop to loop through it, I get an error:

> Error: 0xC001F009 at Get excel data: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::CriteriaID" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

The variable "User::CriteriaID" is defined as string, however, my data in the recordset is like this: 1,2,3A,3B,...

[image]

I try to use a script task to change the data type within the recordset and save it back to the recordset 'User::CriteriaResult'. The code I use it like this:

C#:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::CriteriaResult"].Value);
```

VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim row As DataRow
oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables("User::CriteriaResult").Value)
```

My concept is to create a new datatable, copy data from the recordset and change it to string, then store it back to the recordset and overwrite the old one. But I'm not quite sure how to do so.

Something I have tried:

```
For Each row In dt.Rows
        MsgBox(row.ToString)
    Next row
```

[image]

I got a bunch of rows instead of a row value. Also, I don't know how to save my revised records back to the recordset.

Could you give me any suggestions? Either in VB or C# could both help me a lot.

Comment: .ToString returns the fully qualified name of the type unless Overridden. this is inherited from System.Object (base class for all types)

Answer (score 1):

in VB.net

```
 Private Sub GetValues()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    da.Fill(dt, "Your record set") 'not in quotes
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim index As Integer = 0 ' index of the column you want

For Each row In dt.Rows
     Dim result As String = row(index).ToString
     Debug.Print(result)
Next
```

End Sub

in C#

```
private void GetValues()
{
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt, "Your recordset");//not in  quotes
    Int32 index = 0; //index of the column you need
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            String result = row[index].ToString();
            Debug.Print(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mary, may I know where should I insert my recordset "User::CriteriaResult" to this code?

Comment: Sorry, I was not familiar with that overload of the Fill method. I was concerned with your For loop. I will try to edit my code for a recordset. Be aware that the ADO recordset will, essentially, be discarded after the .Fill and any updates will be handled by ADO.Net.

Comment: Thanks @Mary, that will be great. My ultimately goal is to make the ADO.net accept data type in my object variable. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I hope this helps. Can't test it, but if the .Fill worked for you before it should work now.

Comment: the script itself works well, unfortunately the ADO.net still doesn't pick up my variable.

Comment: Do you have a reference set to ADODB?

Comment: In Visual Studio, on the Project menu choose Add Reference. Under Assemblies, on the left, select Extensions. In the center get a check mark beside ADODB. Then you will be able to code ADODB.Recordset rs = your recordset. put rs in the code in place of  "Your recordset"

Answer (score 1):

Try looping over columns and change the data type for the whole column values, you can use the following code *(using VB.Net)*:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim row As DataRow
oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables("User::CriteriaResult").Value)


For each dCol as DataColumn in dt.Columns

    dCol.DataType = "".GetType()

Next

Dts.Variables("User::CriteriaResult").Value = dt
```

Comment: Hey Hadi, I got an error like this: string is a type in "System" and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: @VerseHe Try using `"".GetType()` instead of `System.String`

Comment: will ".GetType()" change datatype to string? seems like it just get the datatype instead of modify it.

Comment: @VerseHe It is easier to change the column data type rather than loop over all values. And it will give same results

Comment: Hey @Hadi, I agree. I'm trying to follow your way to change the column data type. My confusion is how the code "Gettype()" changes current column data type to string?

Comment: @VerseHe when using `"".GetType()` it will return the *String Data Type*, so when you change all columns data types to string, then the values will be converted automatically to string

Comment: @VerseHe in my answer,  you will loop over columns and change the data type for the whole column values

Comment: @VerseHe you can use any string instead of `""`, example: `"abc".GetType()`

Comment: Thanks @Hadi, I see what you mean. It sounds like I can get data type from a string, that should works well. One more step, do you know if I try to change the data type to binary, what's the sample "abc" I can use?

Comment: @VerseHe `System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]");`. for more infor check this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx